# Как определить каких значений больше всего в столбце?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть данные таблицы, как сделать запрос, чтобы узнать какое id повторяется больше количество раз. Например я хочу узнать user_id каких у него большего всего castle_id. Если я беру user_id =9 то хочу получать castle_id = 1.
И во втором запросе узнать Count rivalCastle_id = 2
Другие запросы получал через session.createQuery.
Не могу понять как составить запрос.
Я пытался таким запросом, но я хочу чтобы бы выдавало только castle_id в первом запросе, а в другом totalCount.Как разделить запрос на 2 части?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT castle_id
FROM heroes3_statistic.games
WHERE user_id = 9
GROUP BY castle_id
HAVING COUNT(castle_id) =
(
  SELECT COUNT(castle_id) totalCount
  FROM heroes3_statistic.games
  WHERE user_id = 9
  GROUP BY castle_id
  ORDER BY totalCount DESC
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: А при чем здесь Java и Hibernate?

Comment: Это ответ или правка к вопросу?